# Heroku Worker Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, unicorn

I'm running Unicorn + Delayed_job on Herkou. I'm getting R14 memory quota exceeded errors when I'm seemingly only using around 246MB out of the 512MB allowed (at 1X worker). Here's a screenshot of my New Relic. I'm not sure how to set number of instances for background worker job. I don't think `WEB_CONCURRENCY` in unicorn.rb controls that but I might be wrong. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Did you fixed ? If yes how?

Comment: It's not fixed. Not sure how. I'm planning to move to Puma.

Comment: I'm having the same issue while using Puma. Did you find a fix for this?